# Angular Token based Auth with CORS

Tags: angularjs, post, authorization, cors

I'm trying to create a cross domain request with angular 1.4.7. I'm pretty new to this topic and especially in this scenario I'm not able to find any help via google.

Environment:
I try to call from the angular app A served by www.a.com the restful api's offered by the server B served by www.b.com.

The thing im struggling over is, that I have to authorise myself a via token in the http post. This token constelation should look like:

```
{
      "account": {
        "hashcode": "somehashcode"
      },
      "hashkey": "somehashkey"
};
```

I tested the api with Postman an it works well, but I'm failing to realise it with angular.

[postman successful try picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PN1w.jpg)
[postman successful try picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKwE9.jpg)

To enable cors in my app.js:

```
.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider){
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"];
  }]);
```

An my request:

```
$http({
   url: 'http://evori-api.azurewebsites.net/api/handshake',
   method: 'POST',
   data: authtoken,
   headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   }
 })
 .then(function(data, status) {
   console.log(data + status);
   }, function() {

   });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Even if you just got an article or blog that explains how such things should be done. I know there is probably just a dumb mistake or something but it drives me crazy.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the problem wasn't me or my api call. The source of the problem was, that the server didn't handle the OPTION call that leads each cors request.